# Magento 2: Do I need to have separate swatches for every configurable product?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-images, configurable-swatches

TL;DR

**Simply put: How to make a configurable product with different images and different prices for each?**

---

To read more:

I was under the assumption that configurable products pull its configuration from other products. If I have 4 options, it will pull the data (price, quantity, image) of the products that are set during the making of the main configurable product.

Let's say I need to create a configurable product (flower bouquet). And this bouquet comes in different arrangements, `good, better, best, and deluxe` and each has its arrangement has its own price, image, and quantity.

**My question is, where do I set the images for a configurable product?**

---

The way I'm doing it now is by:

- Create a new configurable product --> Create configuration
- Select Attributes (I would create a new one for this example)
- I will choose 'visual swatch' for -> Catalog Input Type
- Then I will add options in the section: Manage Options (Values of Your Attribute)

*Now here where I get confused. Do I add the 4 product photos here, in the attribute?*

Because in the next screen, I will also add the details for 4 products. I will set the price, image, quantity, SKU etc.

But at the front end (customer view) the images are being pulled from the switch. (I found out because if I don't set images for the swatch, the little squares under the product title will come blank).

So as for the images I uploaded for each product, what are they for if they won't be shown?

If only the images that come from the switch, does that mean I have to set a different swatch attr for every configurable product?

**So here, I don't upload an image for the swatch:**

[image]

---

**Here, it shows that I have 4 products being set with images:** 
[image]

---

**Obviously, it shows blank squares:**
[image]

**Now I went back and added an image to the attribute (the visual swatch) and refreshed the page:**
[image]

---

**The front end now shows the swatches with images, but when I click on one, it doesn't update the main product image.** Notice I'm selecting an image labeled 2 and hovering over an image labeled 3, and the product shows image labeled 1.

[image]